# How to get user agent styles in javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I was able to get user stylesheets using `document.styleSheets` but I can't find the "user agent" stylesheets.
Is there a way to get default user agent styles?

[image]

Comment: Do you want an element's style in the state where no style is applied or do you explicitly want the user agent stylesheet?  You could probably use [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).  What do you intend to do with this?

Comment: I need the user agent stylesheet

Comment: None of the duplicates describe a way to retrieve style property values from the user agent stylesheet. Voting to reopen this.

Comment: @zero298 It is possible to use `getComputedStyle` but it wouldn't return where the style came from, or whether the style is a browser default or a style from a css file.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/getDefaultComputedStyle

Too bad almost no browser implements it. 